# Strange Scheduler behavior inside a .flatMap() on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I've been attempting to determine why the following code inside the `.flatMap()` operator was shown to be running on the main thread:

```
public Observable<Void> getObservable() {                                                                        
    return jobServiceObservable                                                    
            .flatMap(jobService -> {                                                                             
                if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {                                               
                    Log.d("LooperTest", "On main thread.");                                                      
                } else {                                                                                         
                    Log.d("LooperTest", "Not on main thread.");                                                  
                }                                                                                                

                return jobService.syncReservations(accountUtil.getCurrentAccount());
            })                                                                                                   
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(foregroundScheduler);                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

As you can see, `.subscribeOn()` is being called with `Schedulers.io()`, however the log statements show that the code inside the `.flatMap()` was run on the main thread:

> LooperTest: On main thread.

As a sanity check, I added extra calls to `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to various parts of this code:

```
public Observable<Void> getObservable() {                                                                        
    return jobServiceObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                                                     
            .flatMap(jobService -> {                                                                             
                if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {                                               
                    Log.d("LooperTest", "On main thread.");                                                      
                } else {                                                                                         
                    Log.d("LooperTest", "Not on main thread.");                                                  
                }                                                                                                

                return jobService.syncReservations(accountUtil.getCurrentAccount()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
            })                                                                                                   
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(foregroundScheduler);                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

However, the log statements appear to show the same result. Next, without any code changes, I cleaned the build and restarted my emulator. Upon the next run, the following was printed:

> LooperTest: Not on main thread.

This was odd, as no code changes had been made. Again, without code changes, I cleaned the build and restarted the emulator. On the next run, the following was printed:

> LooperTest: On main thread.

Once again, I cleaned the build, and then closed and opened a new emulator of a different type. Upon running, the following was printed:

> LooperTest: Not on main thread.

Why is this occurring? I suspect there is some odd caching mechanism at play.

Additionally, note that `jobService.syncReservations()` returns a `BehaviorSubject`. Through various searches, it appears that `Subjects` may or may not respect calls to `.subscribeOn()`.

Finally, note that `jobServiceObservable` is injected into the file where the above code is defined. The `jobServiceObservable` is created via the following code:

```
public Observable<JobService> getObservable() {                                                                                              
    return Observable.create(e -> {                                                                                                          
        if (jobServiceBound && jobService != null) {                                                                                         
            e.onNext(jobService);                                                                                                            
            e.onComplete();                                                                                                                  
        } else {                                                                                                                             
            jobServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {                                                                                 
                @Override                                                                                                                    
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {                                                        
                    JobService.JobServiceBinder binder = (JobService.JobServiceBinder) service;                                              
                    jobService = binder.getService();                                                                                        
                    jobServiceBound = true;                                                                                                  

                    e.onNext(jobService);                                                                                                    
                    e.onComplete();                                                                                                          
                }                                                                                                                            

                @Override                                                                                                                    
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {                                                                      
                    reset();                                                                                                                 
                }                                                                                                                            
            };                                                                                                                               
            try {                                                                                                                            
                boolean success = context.bindService(new Intent(context, JobService.class), jobServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                if (!success) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
                    e.onError(new Throwable("The service failed to be bound."));                                                             
                }                                                                                                                            
            } catch (SecurityException exception) {                                                                                                                                                                     
                e.onError(exception);                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                                                    
    });                                                                                                                                      
}
```

An authoritative answer on why the above behavior is occurring is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Because `onServiceConnected` is called on the main thread by the system way after you subscribed to the wrapping `Observable` on the `io()` scheduler. `subscribeOn` tells where further subscription, or in this case, the body of `Observable.create()` should execute. You should use `observeOn` before the `flatMap` so that the mapper function gets executed on the desired thread:

```
public Observable<Void> getObservable() {
    return jobServiceObservable
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(jobService -> {
            if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                Log.d("LooperTest", "On main thread.");
            } else {
                Log.d("LooperTest", "Not on main thread.");
            }

            return jobService.syncReservations(
                accountUtil.getCurrentAccount()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        })
        .observeOn(foregroundScheduler);
}
```

(In contrast, with typical Retrofit network calls, `subscribeOn` works because the network library executes its blocking call on the given scheduler and stays there for the emission of the network response.)

Comment: Thank you for the input. How does this answer explain the differences in log output without code changes as stated in the original question?

Comment: You have the `jobServiceBound && jobService != null` case which I assume got triggered with the clean & restart and thus the `subscribeOn` triggered an immediate emission.